# RegularExpressionValidator doesn't detect empty strings

Tags: asp.net

I have the following regex set as the `ValidationExpression` property on a RegularExpressionValidator in a web form.  When I enter an illegal character in the validated control, the validator detects it and shows an error message.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="categoryPattern" value="^[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-() ]{1,50}$" />
</appSettings>
```

My validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="<%$ AppSettings:categoryPattern %>"
```

My server side validation:

```
Regex rex = new Regex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["categoryPattern"]);
if (!rex.Match(categoryName).Success)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("CategoryName must match expression: " + rex);
```

As you can see, exactly the same pattern is applied client side and server side.

However, when I clear the validated control and submit an empty string, the validator thinks it's OK, and I get an error from my server side validation.  Anyone know what is wrong here, except for the broken contract of the RegularExpressionValidator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is by design. You should also add a `RequiredFieldValidator` to force user entry. `RegularExpressionValidator` assumes empty fields as valid (and doesn't even run them through `Regex`). The reason behind this is that for instance, you might have an optional `Email address 2` field in the form that is not required, but if it's entered, it should be a valid email address. To achieve this easily, other validators ignore empty fields and if you need to make them required, you'd just add another `RequiredFieldValidator`.

In fact, it's not necessary to **manually** revalidate on server. ASP.NET validators also support server-side validation built it. You could just check `Page.IsValid` property.

Comment: Thanks @Mehrdad, I've added a RequiredFieldValidator, but my server validation is not on the page, but in the class used by the page, and potentially other code, so I'm keeping that.